# How to use Witcher 3 Addons downloaded by PSN on PS4

Tags: mods, ps4, the-witcher-3

I have downloaded so many add-ons from PSN like "Alternative look for Ciri", "Alternate look for Yennefer" and they were installed successfully on my PS4. But I didnt see any changes in their appearances in the game. Am I doing something wrong or do I need to do something else also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn the alternative looks on and off.

On the game main menu select 'Downloadable Content'

On the downloadable content menu select 'Options'

You should now be at a menu which lets you enable the alternative looks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I didnt see any option saying 'Downloadable Content' in the main menu. Is it mandatory to update the game to the latest version for this option?

Comment: This is the menu with 'Continue / New Game / Load Game / Options / Downloadable Content' choices. I am running the 1.12 version but the option was in early versions as well, possibly it does not appear if the games does not see any DLC installed.

Comment: I see all the options except the last one. Lemme try this after updating the game. Thanks Greg.